# Shell script to get key value pair from JSON object

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

I have a *JSON* object like

```
 {
  "Men": [
    "All Clothing",
    "All Clothing",
    "All footwear",
    "All footwear",
    "All Watches",
    "All Watches",
    "All Sunglasses",
    "All Sunglasses"
  ],
  "Electronics": [
    "Mobiles",
    "Tablets",
    "Wearable Smart Devices",
    "Mobile Accessories",
    "Headphones and headsets",
    "Tablet Accessories",
    "Computer Accessories",
    "Televisions",
    "Large Appliances",
    "Small Appliances",
    "Kitchen Appliances",
    "Personal Care",
    "Audio and video",
    "Laptop"
  ],
  "Women": [
    "Ethnic wear",
    "Western wear",
    "Lingerie & Sleep Wear",
    "All Bags, Belts & Wallets",
    "All jewellery",
    "All Perfumes",
    "Spectacle Frames",
    "Beauty & Personal Care",
    "The International Beauty Shop"
  ]
}
```

I want to get key value pair from this object.m using jq filter but it doesnot work.

```
keys=`jq 'keys' $categories`
```

$categories is the name of variable of json object. suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really clear what you are asking.  If `$categories` contains your JSON data then you need to pipe it to `jq` somehow.  With Bash, you could use a here string:

```
jq keys <<<"$categories"
```

or more traditionally (and portably), a pipe:

```
printf '%s\n' "$categories" | jq keys
```

To capture the value of the keys into a variable, use a command substitution:

```
keys=$(jq 'keys' <<<"$categories")
```

(or `` `backticks` `` like in your attempt; but the modern notation is much preferable);

or better yet, obtain this value in the same way you assigned `categories` in the first place.